# New issue after refactoring my code: "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing an app in Vue.js 2 with Typescript using the vue-property-decorator attributes.  I recently decided to refactor most of my code and now every time I pass a binded property to my vue components through the @Prop decorator I get an error saying something like:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "pager". Expected PagerSettings, got Object
```

The worst part about all of this is that the app still functions correctly, it's just throwing an ugly error message to my browser console. Everything works perfectly without an error if I change my property to type "any" but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of using Typescript in the first place.

I searched through a bunch of answers for the same problem and the solution was always "you're not passing what you think you're passing". I'm 99% sure this isn't the case. This happens with every single prop I pass to a component, regardless of type. After I started a new project from a boilerplate template and brought all my code back in, this started happening.

My tsconfig.json is exactly the same and as far as I can see, all of the versions in my package.json match the previous project. I started looking at the vue.config.js and it's almost identical with a few slight changes, but nothing that would effect the way way variables are passed through the @Prop directive.

Has anyone else experienced this before? What else can I even look at to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: can you add an example of your component with the prop and another were you are passing the prop

Comment: @larizzatg not sure I can easily repro this.  My component code is exactly the same as it was before I updated all the boilerplate stuff and it worked fine. The only thing that's different is the way I'm initializing the VueJS app, and my vue.config.js file.  Is there anything in VueJS configurations that would make this happen? Is there some type of strict checking I wasn't doing before but am now?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to solve your issue if you don't provide a [mcve]? *"... is exactly as it was before"* doesn't give much to go on for anyone trying to debug your code. How are they going to test any potential fix? Use codesanbox.io or similar. And make sure it reproduces the bug.

Comment: What I do is to create a  simple component were I can reproduce the problem, sometimes with codesandbox or codepen

Comment: @tao I understand what you're saying. I was kind of hoping someone would know of something like "Oh yeah, if your config is set to this, you'll get those type checking errors". Or even "set it this way, and type checking doesn't happen on the client". I'll try and build an example and post it.

Comment: @larizzatg the problem I have is I haven't found a code pen type site that lets me do VueJS in TypeScript using vue-property-decorator package.

Comment: copy/paste your `package.json` into codesandbox.io. You'll then have the exact same environment, as you have the same packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this is happening all of a sudden, but I was able to figure out a way around it. Originally I was declaring my props like this:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class Pagination extends Vue {

    @Prop()
    public pager: Pager;

}
```

I got it to work by defining the type like this

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { PropType } from 'vue';

@Component({})
export default class Pagination extends Vue {

    @Prop({ type: Object as PropType<Pager> })
    public pager: Pager;

}
```

Comment: what version of vue are you using?

Comment: @larizzatg  vue 2.6.12   and vue-property-decorator 8.4.2.

Comment: So I'm a newbie with vue+ts, recently using it with vue-3 + composition API so I don't really use the class syntax and in the tutos I always see the PropType generic for object props, but searching in SO it seems that this was added in previous versions and the other way to do it it's declaring the prop in the component decorator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890810/declare-typescript-interface-props-in-vuejs-class-component

Comment: @larizzatg that's good to know, thanks! I wonder if it would have the same issue if I declared it there.  I don't know if I like the way it looks though. Something about having all of my properties defined in the class like that makes me feel good.  I come from a C# background so it's pretty awesome when JavaScript feels similar.